# get Maven to spit out ONLY the version of a project (not other stuff starting with [INFO])

Tags: windows, maven

I used `2.1.1:evalute -Dexpression=project.version` to get the version of my project, but that would also print other stuff to standard out.
Is there anyway to 'turn off' those `[INFO]` lines?

I imagine it should be possible to only get the value of the evaluated expression, which, in this case, is the version.

This is on Windows, so I can't `grep` or `awk` the thing, by the way.

```
  C:\Users\Owner\ mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate  \         
  -Dexpression=project.version

    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building myproject
    [INFO]    task-segment: [org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate] (e)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] [help:evaluate {execution: default-cli}]
    0.1.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
    [INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 28 17:42:49 EDT 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/106M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is the `-q` command line option on newer versions of maven.

It may not strip everything, but should strip the noise

Comment: I have `3.0.4`, and I believe the latest is `3.0.5`. Would that work?

Comment: `3.0.4` supports the CLI option IIRC... I may have to turn on the MBP and put the tablet down to confirm though ;-)

Comment: I've just tried adding `-q` to the command, and it printed nothing (literally nothing) ... Hm..

Comment: Yes... I can confirm the same on Mac OSX... Pity. You can get `grep` for windows though

Comment: As you might've guessed, I wanted to use this in my build-script, and I can't really expect the user to have `grep` on Windows.... But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Redirect output to a file and then use `findstr /v` to search that temp file

Comment: -q removes everything including the proper output of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Even there is no `grep` on `Windows`, there is a [findStr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/findstr.mspx?mfr=true).

> **/l** : Uses search strings literally.
>
> **/r** : Uses search strings as ***regular expressions***. Findstr interprets all metacharacters as regular expressions unless you use **/l**.

Furthermore there is [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) provided by the [GNUWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) as well.

I hope this may help.